# Changing website background for bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing some tutorials on web development with Django (I'm a complete beginner). I have downloaded [this](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/) bootstrap theme and succesfully implemented it for my future website.

What I would like now is to personalise this bootstrap theme by changing the default background. The "grayscale" theme css is referred to like this:

```
<!-- Theme CSS -->
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'aboutme/css/grayscale.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

(I'm sure that this is what gives my webpage the grayscale theme, since when I delete these lines, the grayscale theme on my website is gone.)

Looking in the "grayscale.min.css" file, I find the following line:

```
{display:table;height:auto;padding:100px 0;text-
align:center;color:#fff;background:url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) bottom 
center no-repeat #000;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-
size:cover;background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover}
```

I guess this is where the background is set since the intro-bg.jpg in the img map is the grayscale background picture. However, when I try to change the background like:

```
background:url(../img/mybackground.jpg)
```

It doesn't work! The strange thing is that it seems like the site doesn't need the "grayscale.min.css" file at all; when I delete all its content and save it, nothing changes for my site! I don't get this since, like I mentioned earlier, when I delete the line:

`{% load staticfiles %} 
<link href="{% static 'aboutme/css/grayscale.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`

The site **does** change!

**Q:** How do I solve this and change the background for my website?

Comment: First, try using the developer tools in chrome (right-click->inspect) to check where the background image is coming from. Second, I think the css is getting stored in your browser cache. Try a plugin to clear cache.

Comment: @chatuur Thanks a lot man! Clearing the cache worked!

Comment: I'm posting the same answer if you're satisfied with the answer, please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the browser, sometimes CSS files are cached in the browser. 
That is why the changes you're making in the CSS files are not getting reflected.

Most browsers have plugins which allow you to clear cache. 
[Here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en) is a guide to clear cache on chrome if you don't want to download a plugin.